# Задачка пятый класс на площадь, плитку и щели между ней

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Программа, которая рассчитывает максимальное возможное количество цельных плиток на полу при этом между плитками есть зазоры(щели).

Размер плитки это константа - 20 х 30 см,
между соседними плитками есть щель, шириной 2 или 3 или 4 или 5 мм, ширина щели меняется в алгоритме, а не вводится пользователем. Ширина везде одинаковая. По периметру площади не должно быть щели.

Вводом программы будет длина и ширина площади в сантиметрах(целое число) - два целых числа, разделенных запятой и пробелом.

Выводом программы будет максимальное количество целых плиток и если плиток больше одной, то  ширина щели(от 2 до 5 мм).

То есть мы ищем такой способ укладки плитки и стыков(щелей) между ними, чтобы площадь комнаты была максимально заполнена ЦЕЛЫМИ плитками и был выбран максимальный размер щели. Считаются только ЦЕЛЫЕ плитки, все плитки должны быть одинаково ориентированы - их длинные стороны должны быть параллельными.
Пример расположения щелей и плитки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например если ввести 122 и 202, то выводом будет 36 плиток и щель 4,
Если ввести 31 и 21, то вывод будет 1 плитка.

Как это решить?

---

Вот как-то у меня вышло, объясните пожалуйста 
[image: Вот такое у меня получилось]

---

Чет не понимаю почему не работает и как вывести гап,

```
#include <stdio.h>

//count
int max_count(int room_w, int room_h, int tile_w, int tile_h, int gap){
        room_w += gap;
        room_h += gap;
        tile_w += gap;
        tile_h += gap;
        int max = ( ( (room_w / tile_w) * (room_h / tile_h) ) > ( (room_w / tile_h) * (room_h / tile_w) ) ) 
            ? ((room_w / tile_w) * (room_h / tile_h)) 
            : ((room_w / tile_h) * (room_h / tile_w));
    return max;
}//count

//main
int main(){
    int w, h;

    printf(" Ширина и длина ");
    if(scanf("%d, %d", &w, &h) != 2){
        printf("Error!\n");
    return 1;
    }
    if(w <= 0 || h <= 0 || w * h < 600){
        printf("Error\n");
    return 1;
    } 

    int supermax = ( max_count(w * 10, h * 10, 300, 200, 2) > max_count(w * 10, h * 10, 300, 200, 3))
        ?  max_count(w * 10, h * 10, 300, 200, 2)
        :  max_count(w * 10, h * 10, 300, 200, 3);

    supermax = (supermax > max_count(w * 10, h * 10, 300, 200, 4))
        ?  supermax
        :  max_count(w * 10, h * 10, 300, 200, 4);

    supermax = (supermax > max_count(w * 10, h * 10, 300, 200, 5))
        ?  supermax
        :  max_count(w * 10, h * 10, 300, 200, 5);


    if(supermax == 1){
        printf("плиток  %d", supermax);
    } else printf("плиток: %d  щели: ", supermax);  
return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102347/discussion-on-question-by----------).

Answer (score 0):

С использованием целочисленного деления, с учётом `По периметру пола не должно быть щели`:

```
X*A + (X-1)*B = Wdt
X*A + X*B - B = Wdt
X*A + X*B = Wdt + B
X * (A + B) =  Wdt + B  
X = (Wdt + B) / (A + B) 


#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int tiles_count(int room_w, int room_h, int tile_w, int tile_h, int gap)
{
    room_w += gap;
    room_h += gap;
    tile_w += gap;
    tile_h += gap;
    return std::max((room_w / tile_w) * (room_h / tile_h), (room_w / tile_h) * (room_h / tile_w));
}

int main()
{
    int besttiles = 0, tiles;
    int bestgap;
    for (int gap = 5; gap >= 2; gap--) {
        tiles = tiles_count(1220, 2020, 300, 200, gap);
        std::cout << "tiles " << tiles << " gap " << gap << std::endl;
        if (tiles > besttiles) {
            besttiles = tiles;
            bestgap = gap;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "besttiles "<< besttiles << " bestgap " << bestgap << std::endl;    

tiles 36 gap 5
tiles 36 gap 4
tiles 36 gap 3
tiles 40 gap 2
----------------
besttiles 40 bestgap 2
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102348/discussion-on-answer-by-mbo---------).

Comment: Если щель 2мм, то получится 40 плиток?

Comment: Точно, в таком случае вмещается 4x10

Comment: Так, тогда я совсем не понимаю задание, потому что  в задание дан пример, где задается 122 на 202  и почему-то выбирается толщина зазора 4, и выходит 36 плиток

Comment: Точная формулировка задания есть?

Comment: Ну она выше, в посте

Comment: Указанная постановка задачи страдает от неоднозначности `ширина щели меняется в алгоритме, а не вводится пользователем.`, вы и сами об этом говорили.

Comment: кажется я понял, сравнивать надо не количество черепиц, а площадь ими заполненную, наверное с щелями

Comment: А как же `рассчитывает максимальное возможное количество цельных плиток ` ?

Comment: я устал, не знаю как это решить

Comment: Ну алгоритм расчёта есть, а остальное относится к точности постановки задачи.

Comment: ну как определить нужную щель?

Comment: Если условие - выбрать максимально широкую щель, при которой достигается максимальное количество плиток (приоритет за этим) - то так, как я написал.

Comment: Можно код. пожалуйста

Comment: Он же в ответе.

Comment: А почему в примере, ответ 36 и  4 ?

Comment: Может надо как можно больше площадь занять цельными плитками?

Comment: Цельные плитки и считаются

Comment: Ну тогда почему в примере, ответ 36 и 4, а не 40 и 2?

Comment: Не знаю........

Comment: А у нас случайно щель между стеной и плиткой не появляется ?